Azure Pipelines, Using Bash Output Variables in conditions on jobs is not working correctly
So I am trying to set up my YAML file to run a build on my 2 Databases only if there are changes in their respective git folder. Which the bash script below correctly runs and provides out the True/False flags.
Bash Script:
         set -x
          pathFilterDB1="DB1/"
          pathFilterDB2="DB2/"

          changedFiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD)

          DB1Changed=false
          DB2Changed=false

          if [[ -n "$changedFiles" ]]; then
            for file in $changedFiles; do
              [[ "$file" == $pathFilterDB1* ]] && DB1Changed=true
              [[ "$file" == $pathFilterDB2* ]] && DB2Changed=true
            done
          fi

          echo "DB1_CHANGED: $DB1Changed"
          echo "STAGING_CHANGED: $DB2Changed"

          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DB1_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$DB1Changed "
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DB2_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$DB2Changed "

And the Azure Pipeline condition below seems to pull output, but is always pulling an additional 2 Single " ' "
condition: eq(dependencies.CheckChanges.outputs[bashchanges.DB1_CHANGED], 'true')
condition: eq(dependencies.CheckChanges.outputs[bashchanges.DB2_CHANGED], 'true') 

Here is what it evaluates as:
Evaluating: eq(dependencies['CheckChanges']['outputs']['bashchanges.DB1_CHANGED'], 'true')
Expanded: eq('true''', 'true')
Result: False

Evaluating: eq(dependencies['CheckChanges']['outputs']['bashchanges.DB2_CHANGED'], 'true')
Expanded: eq('true''', 'true')
Result: False

This condition is done for 2 different jobs.
When I change the DB1 Condition below:
condition: eq(dependencies.CheckChanges.outputs[bashchanges.DB1_CHANGED], 'true''')
condition: eq(dependencies.CheckChanges.outputs[bashchanges.DB1_CHANGED], 'true')

I get these responses:
Evaluating: eq(dependencies['CheckChanges']['outputs']['bashchanges.DB1_CHANGED'], 'true''')
Expanded: eq('true', 'true''')

Evaluating: eq(dependencies['CheckChanges']['outputs']['bashchanges.DB2_CHANGED'], 'true')
Expanded: eq('false', 'true')

I for the life of me can't figure out if it's an additional ' somewhere or if there's something else I should be looking for.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - test
      - prod

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:

  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  dacpacLocation: 'D:\a\1\s\Staging\bin\Release\Staging.dacpac'
  
  storageAccountName: 'azseastorageasrdev'
  containerName: 'asrbackup'
  blobName: 'staging_$(Build.BuildId)_$(Date:yyyyMMddHHmmss).dacpac'
  storageAccountKey: 'key'

  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'prod') }}:
    serverName: 'database.windows.net'
    stagingDatabaseName: 'azsea-rda-prod-staging-db'
    reportingDatabaseName: 'azsea-rda-prod-reporting-db'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'test') }}:
    serverName: '.database.windows.net'
    stagingDatabaseName: 'azsea-rda-test-staging-db'
    reportingDatabaseName: 'azsea-rda-test-reporting-db'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
    serverName: 'azsea-rda-dev-sql.database.windows.net'
    stagingDatabaseName: 'azsea-rda-dev-staging-db'
    reportingDatabaseName: 'azsea-rda-dev-reporting-db'

jobs:
- job: CheckChanges
  displayName: 'Check for changes'
  steps:
      # Checkout code and fetch the full Git history
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0  # Fetch all commit history, not just the latest commit
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          set -x
          pathFilterReporting="Reporting/"
          pathFilterStaging="Staging/"

          changedFiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD)

          reportingChanged=false
          stagingChanged=false

          if [[ -n "$changedFiles" ]]; then
            for file in $changedFiles; do
              [[ "$file" == $pathFilterReporting* ]] && reportingChanged=true
              [[ "$file" == $pathFilterStaging* ]] && stagingChanged=true
            done
          fi

          echo "REPORTING_CHANGED: $reportingChanged"
          echo "STAGING_CHANGED: $stagingChanged"

          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPORTING_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$reportingChanged "
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=STAGING_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$stagingChanged "
      name: bashchanges




- job: BuildAndDeployReporting
  displayName: "Build and Deploy Reporting DB"
  dependsOn: CheckChanges
  condition: eq(dependencies.CheckChanges.outputs[bashchanges.REPORTING_CHANGED], 'true')
  steps: 
    - script: echo "Building and Deploying Reporting DB"
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        scriptType: 'Inline'
        inlineScript: |
          $netFramework472Url = "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/13815836/10ad8c401f59cda96ab9a5c155cdc394/ndp472-devpack-enu.exe"
          
          $netFramework472Installed = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
          
          if ($null -eq $netFramework472Installed -or $netFramework472Installed.Release -lt 461808) {
              Write-Host ".NET Framework 4.7.2 is not installed. Installing..."
              
              Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $netFramework472Url -OutFile "$env:TEMP\ndp472-devpack-enu.exe"
              
              Start-Process -FilePath "$env:TEMP\ndp472-devpack-enu.exe" -ArgumentList "/quiet /norestart" -Wait
              
              Write-Host ".NET Framework 4.7.2 installation complete."
          }
          else {
              Write-Host ".NET Framework 4.7.2 is already installed."
          }
        displayName: 'Install .NET Framework 4.7.2'
    
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: 'Reporting/Reporting.sqlproj'
      displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: 'Reporting/Reporting.sqlproj'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=$(buildConfiguration)'
        platform: 'Any CPU'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'  
        artifactName: 'DatabaseBuildArtifacts'           
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

    - publish: D:\a\1\s\Reporting\bin\Release\
      artifact: dacpac
      displayName: 'Publish DACPAC Artifact'

    - script: |
        echo 'Uploading DACPAC to Azure Blob Storage...'
        az storage blob upload --account-name "$(storageAccountName)" --container-name "$(containerName)" --name "$(blobName)" --file "$(dacpacLocation)" --account-key "$(storageAccountKey)" --overwrite
      displayName: 'Upload DACPAC to Azure Storage'

    - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Azure Resource - Main - Subscription Level'
        authenticationType: 'server'
        serverName: '$(serverName)'  
        databaseName: '$(reportingDatabaseName)'  
        sqlUsername: 'username'  
        sqlPassword: 'pwd'  
        deployType: 'DacpacTask'
        dacpacFile: '$(dacpacLocation)'
        additionalArguments: '/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true'
        IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
        DeleteFirewallRule: true

- job: BuildAndDeployStaging
  displayName: 'Build and Deploy Staging DB'
  dependsOn: CheckChanges
  condition: eq(dependencies.CheckChanges.outputs['bashchanges.STAGING_CHANGED'], 'true')
  steps: 
    - script: echo "Building and Deploying Staging DB"

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        scriptType: 'Inline'
        inlineScript: |
          $netFramework472Url = "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/13815836/10ad8c401f59cda96ab9a5c155cdc394/ndp472-devpack-enu.exe"
          
          $netFramework472Installed = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
          
          if ($null -eq $netFramework472Installed -or $netFramework472Installed.Release -lt 461808) {
              Write-Host ".NET Framework 4.7.2 is not installed. Installing..."
              
              Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $netFramework472Url -OutFile "$env:TEMP\ndp472-devpack-enu.exe"
              
              Start-Process -FilePath "$env:TEMP\ndp472-devpack-enu.exe" -ArgumentList "/quiet /norestart" -Wait
              
              Write-Host ".NET Framework 4.7.2 installation complete."
          }
          else {
              Write-Host ".NET Framework 4.7.2 is already installed."
          }
        displayName: 'Install .NET Framework 4.7.2'

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: 'Staging/Staging.sqlproj'
      displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: 'Staging/Staging.sqlproj'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=$(buildConfiguration)'
        platform: 'Any CPU'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'  
        artifactName: 'DatabaseBuildArtifacts'           
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

    - publish: D:\a\1\s\Staging\bin\Release\
      artifact: dacpac
      displayName: 'Publish DACPAC Artifact'

    - script: |
        echo 'Uploading DACPAC to Azure Blob Storage...'
        az storage blob upload --account-name "$(storageAccountName)" --container-name "$(containerName)" --name "$(blobName)" --file "$(dacpacLocation)" --account-key "$(storageAccountKey)" --overwrite
      displayName: 'Upload DACPAC to Azure Storage'

    - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Azure Resource - Main - Subscription Level'
        authenticationType: 'server'
        serverName: '$(serverName)'  
        databaseName: '$(stagingDatabaseName)'  
        sqlUsername: 'username'  
        sqlPassword: 'pwd'  
        deployType: 'DacpacTask'
        dacpacFile: '$(dacpacLocation)'
        additionalArguments: '/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true'
        IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
        DeleteFirewallRule: true


Please provide the complete YAML content of your pipeline in your question post.

Updated with Yaml.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same YAML code as yours.
The reason of the issue that you give an extra whitespace to the values of the output variables when using the setvariable command to set the output variables.
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPORTING_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$reportingChanged "
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=STAGING_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$stagingChanged "

After removing the extra whitespace, the extra ' get removed from the values of the output variables, and the condition can get the correct the output values.
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPORTING_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$reportingChanged"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=STAGING_CHANGED;isOutput=true]$stagingChanged"


EDIT:
In the Bash script, changing the command lines
from
[[ "$file" == $pathFilterReporting* ]] && reportingChanged=true
[[ "$file" == $pathFilterStaging* ]] && stagingChanged=true

to
if [[ "$file" == $pathFilterReporting* ]]; then
  reportingChanged=true
fi

if [[ "$file" == $pathFilterStaging* ]]; then
  stagingChanged=true
fi

does not make any effect.
I attempted the following Bash script that directly set the values on the setvariable command, but it still will have an extra ' character on the values sometimes.
  - bash: |
      set -x
      pathFilterReporting="Reporting/"
      pathFilterStaging="Staging/"

      changedFiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD)

      if [[ -n "$changedFiles" ]]; then
        for file in $changedFiles; do
          if [[ "$file" = $pathFilterReporting* ]]; then
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPORTING_CHANGED;isoutput=true]true'
          fi
          
          if [[ "$file" = $pathFilterStaging* ]]; then
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=STAGING_CHANGED;isoutput=true]true'
          fi
        done
      fi
    name: bashchanges

Based on my further investigation, the problem seems is with Bash (or Bash task) itself. When I convert the Bash script to be a PowerShell script like as below, and then execute the PowerShell script using a PowerShell task (pwsh or powershell), everything can always work fine.
  - pwsh: |
      $pathFilterReporting = "Reporting/"
      $pathFilterStaging = "Staging/"

      $changedFiles = git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD
      foreach ($file in $changedFiles)
      {
        if ($file -match "^$pathFilterReporting.*")
        {
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPORTING_CHANGED;isoutput=true]true"
        }

        if ($file -match "^$pathFilterStaging.*")
        {
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=STAGING_CHANGED;isoutput=true]true"
        }
      }
    name: bashchanges

With above configuration:

When there are modified files contained in the Reporting folder, set the output variable REPORTING_CHANGED with true value. The condition on the BuildAndDeployReporting returns True, and the job gets run.
Expanded: eq('true', 'true')
Result: True


When there are not modified files contained in the Reporting folder, not set the output variable REPORTING_CHANGED. The condition on the BuildAndDeployReporting job returns False, and the job gets skipped.
Expanded: eq(Null, 'true')
Result: False


When there are modified files contained in the Staging folder, set the output variable STAGING_CHANGED with true value. The condition on the BuildAndDeployStaging returns True, and the job gets run.
Expanded: eq('true', 'true')
Result: True


When there are not modified files contained in the Staging folder, not set the output variable STAGING_CHANGED. The condition on the BuildAndDeployStaging job returns False, and the job gets skipped.
Expanded: eq(Null, 'true')
Result: False





That was 1 issue, I think the actual issue was having the check for both changes inside the same if statement.
Doing the below seems to of fixed my issue. Walking away for a couple hours seems to work wonders.
          if [[ -n "$changedFiles" ]]; then
            for file in $changedFiles; do
              if [[ "$file" == $pathFilterReporting* ]]; then
                reportingChanged=true
              fi

              if [[ "$file" == $pathFilterStaging* ]]; then
                stagingChanged=true
              fi
            done
          fi

Thanks.

@TobiasShand, The change seems does not make any effect. Based on my further investigation, the problem seems is with Bash (or Bash task) itself. Try to convert the Bash script to be a PowerShell script. For more details, see EDIT in my above answer.

Confirming that works, I am also seeing the same problem with the bash script. I Attempted to write out the ouputs using CMD, Powershell and BASH in a seperate job and all had the extra '.
Thanks for the powershell version it is working now, I'll avoid the Bash Task for now.
